# Replace Version Info Resource

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm Loading a certain Exe in My Program and I'm trying to replace It's Version Info Resource.
I'm Using UpdateResource() but for some reason It isn't replacing the original resource as it is supposed to do.

```
UpdateResource(hHandle,RT_VERSION,"1",MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH,SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US),pRsrcMemory,rsrcSize)
```

When The Exe is opened in a resource editor , I see two version Info resources with the same ID 1 , But the Version Info Displayed in Windows Explorer is the Original Info.(Probably because it comes first in the .rsrc section of the exe but i'm not sure)

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource IDs can be either strings or numbers.  Which is the problem here, it is not resource ID "1", it is MAKEINTRESOURCE(1).

Fun puzzler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you following all the steps called out for in the MSDN for updating [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources)? Namely:

1. Use the BeginUpdateResource function to open an update handle to your exe.
2. Use the UpdateResource function to update it.
3. Use the EndUpdateResource function to complete the update.

Comment: Yes , And I'm "Adding" New Resources Just fine with the same routine , but I just can't seem to replace the Version Info resource.